# Is there any way to partition dimension on SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-2016

I have a cube where measure group is partitioned by current year and last years.and I processed every night just current year partition . it is effected in performance of process in fact but dimension is too slow in process.I'd like to set the partition for dimension same as measure group that is said , but I don't know how do it and I surfaced the net but I don't know what to search so could any one help me?

thank's a lot

Comment: What version of SQL server do you have?

Comment: Sql server 2016

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/create-partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2016

Answer (score 1):

In SSAS Multidimensional dimensions can not be partitioned, only measure groups are available for partitioning.